# Issue while using up and down arrows in Firefox

Tags: javascript, addthis

I am working in addthis widget .there I am doing selection among the items with up and down arrow keys both are working means I am able to select the items by using up and down arrows with Google Chrome .as I mentioned same functionality not at all working with Firefox meaning not able to select the items from the list with the arrows keys .I have tried enable smooth scrolling from Firefox ,caret browsing but no use .

Comment: What kind of an answer are you expecting to get for this question?

Comment: I have checked few posts there I have seen there is no support for up and down keys .is that true that what I have seen

Comment: I can make my FF to do what ever I want with the arrow keys ...

Comment: Hey buddy I could not be able to do with FF in my system div is the HTML element inside all are anchor tags I am not sure why it's not working in Firefox and perfectly working in chrome

Comment: Yes, but why are you stating that here at SO? We can't debug a code we can't see.

Comment: I got that ,we can't see in debuggging .my expectation is , is there any browser settings supposed to be changed so that it will work as expected

Comment: Based on the given information, we can only say, that you're doing something wrong ...